# Assembled PCB not working. Any ideas? (round 2)

Tags: pcb, soldering, short-circuit

Attached are schematics and an image of a circuit I made for a project. I asked this question months ago with an earlier iteration of the circuit and finally got around to assembling it on a single, new PCB. There is one important problem:

The wall-wart (12V 1A) simply blinks rather than work normally. It is a nameless wholesale wall-wart, but still worked reliably. I suspect I may have a short somewhere, or hopefully I simply added one through shoddy assembly.

[image: Schematic of PCB seen in the footprint below]
Schematic of PCB seen in the footprint below

[image: Footprint of PCB used]
Footprint of PCB used

[image: Schematic of the PCB with the addition of a jumper wire]
Schematic of the PCB with the addition of a jumper wire

[image: Image of the PCB as assembled and tested]
Image of the PCB as assembled and tested

[image: Top view of blank PCB]
Top view of blank PCB

[image: Bottom view of blank PCB. The orange jumper (seen in pictures above) runs from the "INPUT +" to "OUTPUT +"]
Bottom view of blank PCB. The orange jumper (seen in pictures above) runs from the "INPUT +" to "OUTPUT +"

Possible errors and how I have addressed them (with the intent of eliminating them in the next iteration):

a. holes for photoresistor pins too small–– fixed by filing down pins until they fit and then adjusting the footprint for next version

b. LED+ does not connect to input+ 12V –– fixed through a jumper visible only in the pictures. Next version will include that connection

c. Solder-joints poor–– admittedly KitchenAid is not known for their reflow solder systems, nonetheless this time around the solder paste (same paste as last time) barely melted after 8 minutes and it was only by centering the PCB on the oven rack that by minute 13 it had melted. (280F convection bake, I think normal bake works better) I touched up the capacitors later, manually soldered all THT parts, and the MCU was soldered and desoldered many times manually. An incorrect footprint for the LED also contributed to this, but it should still work based on the dimensions.

BOM: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrnyYMaL4LTUEdR-Fa35R20bMgI528D4ixzeeOuktbI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a bench power supply? Something that will show you the current draw of a load? Whenever I test a prototype of anything, the rule is to current-limit the supply and monitor current draw. If it's not within expected limits, there may be a short/fault. If you don't current-limit, you could release magic smoke, rendering the diagnosis of failure much more complicated (since now you may have multiple failures).

Comment: Did you check for power shorts with a DMM ohmmeter. Power off of course.

Comment: The PCB drawing looks like the red traces short out a lot of pins. Please post a photo of an empty PCB. Zoom in so that there is less table and more PCB compared to the current picture.

Comment: @Justme I've added photos of the blank PCB.

Comment: @JYelton Sorry if this is elementary, but what is the reasoning behind checking current draw? I do not have a bench power supply, but I do have a multimeter. My trouble is that there is negligible voltage right now, I think because of a short and the wall-wart's diodes protecting it. No magic smoke and the supply is able to provide around 15% more current than the entire circuit needs at its maximum (when all lights are on).

Comment: @Mattman944 Where specifically should I check for shorts? Is there a method I can refer to? (sorry if this is basic knowledge)  I have been checking for continuity between the input voltage terminals and solder joints that looked bad and found nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Measure the power input resistance of bare board and assembled board and report in question

Comment: I would cut or desolder the input pin of the 7805, so only the input caps and wiring are in circuit, and check again. If the power still fails, then the short is in the input wiring. If the power works, the short is in the 5V circuit. Solder the regulator pin back together afterwards.

Comment: CV only power supply for prototype stage is either very brave or asking for problems. Lab power supply, CC limit, check consumption against calculation.

Comment: @Lorenzo The reasoning is if you expect your board to draw 100 mA, when you connect it to a current-limited supply (say at 200 mA) and it immediately reaches 200 mA and stays there, you know you have a short, or a component failure, etc. If you were to connect it to a supply that's not current limited, and it can deliver a lot more, then you can potentially destroy any component affected by the fault.

Comment: Is that a board from expresspcb? I hate their HASL finish, doesn't solder as nice as the ENIG from oshpark.

Comment: What's the black thing in the solder blob below the INPUT text in silk screen? Looks like 0402 resistor with both sides shorted in the blob, but it's hard to tell. Maybe melted cable insulation from a botched peeling job?

Comment: @Bryan it's JLCPCB. Usually decent, although lead times and shipping costs have increased a lot in the last couple years.

Answer (score 6):

Do things step by step. Start with a fresh board. Connect to a lab power supply. Ensure there's no current draw. Then add the components in front of the 7805. Try again. Then add the 7805. Try again. And so on.

The quality of the assembly process seen on the photograph is likely the source of all the trouble: there's no proper reflow of the joints, and there likely are solder whiskers that bridge things together.

For example, just a 7805 with capacitors should draw under 10mA.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain the process behind ensuring there's no current draw? Is the idea that I build another copy of the board only without the power regulation components, and then measure the current draw using an external power supply? By "in front of" do you mean a specific group of components or just that I should generally test chunks of the board at a time? Thank you for your answer and I apologize if I am asking you to repeat something straightforward.

Comment: @Lorenzo The goal here is to check that each functionality of your board is OK before soldering the next one. Thus the suggestion is to start by the power supply block of your board; Check it; and then solder the next part and so on. Why we are talking about the power drawn ? it's because it's an indication of good or bad behavior of the board and it's easy to measure. If you solder your 7805 with its surrounding caps, you know that, by design, this should not draws hundreds of mili-amps but only a small current. Thus if you measure too much current: you have a problem and you know where it is